# Virtualbox machine requires more and more memory

Tags: virtualbox

Virtualbox machine running win7x64 memory is limited however while instance is running and different processes are being started/finished on it host machine on Windows 10 x64 keeps "loosing" available memory until vbox instance is restarted.

Tried changing different memory options in vbox settings with no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `VirtualBoxVM.exe` to Windows Defender Exclusions finally fixed this case. Can't see any linear memory usage growth since this change.